# Flutter : Deselect value in an array of listview in MultiSelectContainer

Tags: flutter, dart

I implemented flutter `MultiSelectContainer` so I can implement the multiple item selection of my array which works perfectly. But I am facing an issue in implementing the logic that when an item is not selected in an increasing order without skipping any item e.g Array range from 1 to 3 user selects an item indexing from 0->1->2 without jumping the order. I tried to implement an if statement as below to check if the current select item `-1` is equal to the previous select item, in this case, the current select item is `selectedItem` which is the single item selected, and the previously selected item which I made used `allSelectedItems[allSelectedItems.length - 2]` to extract from an array of `allSelectedItems` and my code inside `onChanged:` looks like below:

```
  if(allSelectedItems.length>1) {

      var lst = allSelectedItems[allSelectedItems.length - 2];

      var pos = lst.toString().lastIndexOf('-');

      String previousResult = (pos != -1)? lst.substring(0, pos): lst;
                                                    
      var pos1 = selectedItem.toString().lastIndexOf('-');

      String currResult = (pos1 != -1)? selectedItem.substring(0, pos1): selectedItem;
                                                   
      if(int.parse(currResult)-1  == int.parse(previousResult)){
                                                       debugPrint("Correct order");
                                                       }else{

                                                selectedItem = !selectedItem.isSelect();
                                                       }

                                                      }
```

In the above `if(allSelectedItems.length>1)` is to skip the first select item as you need to compare the previous and current selected item and `selectedItem=!selectedItem.isSelect();` is meant to deselect item that is not in order that was selected but didn't work. Below is what `MultiSelectContainer` looks like:

```
MultiSelectContainer(controller: controllerMultipleSelect,
                     itemsPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                     itemsDecoration: MultiSelectDecorations(
                                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color: Colors.white
                                                        border: Border.all(color: 
                                                                Colors.grey[100]),
                                                        borderRadius: 
                                                         BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                                    selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: colorBlue,
                                                      border:Border.all(color:colorBlue),
                                                      
                                                borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5)),),

                                                     

                                                    showInListView: true,
                                                    listViewSettings: ListViewSettings(
                                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(
                                                          width: 10,
                                                        )),

                                                    items: List.generate(dataSchedule == null ? 0 : dataSchedule.length,
                                                            (index) => MultiSelectCard(
                                                          scheduleDeselect,
                                                              value: index.toString() +"-"+ dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'], label: dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'],)),
                                                    onChange: (allSelectedItems, selectedItem) {



}),
```

From the above since you can only asset `index` inside `items:` I had to parse the `index` inside `value:` and extract it in `onChange:`. I am open to any other way. I just want to be able to unselect item that is not in order as stated above and the value shouldn't be added to array of `allSelectedItems`. Thanks in advance my flutter version is `flutter_multi_select_items: ^0.4.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to post this answer as it worked for me and for anyone facing a similar issue. I tried all I can to work with `MultiSelectContainer` but all didn't work so I change my approach as below:

```
  String selectedToTime =" ";
  List<bool> toTimeListSelect =[];

   timeListSelect(){

    for(int i=0; i< dataSchedule.length;i++){
      toTimeListSelect.add(false);
    }
  }

  List<String> arrayTimeStored = [];
  List<String> arrayTimeIndexStored = [];

  List<String> arrayTimeListed = [];

  Widget toTime(){
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      height: 60,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: dataSchedule == null ? 0 : dataSchedule.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){

           return GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15,left: 15),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3,left: 3),
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'].toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: toTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.white : colorBlack,fontSize: 16 ),)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: toTimeListSelect[index] ? colorBlue : Colors.white,
                  borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius
                      .circular(
                      5.0),
                  border:Border.all(color:index== _selectedIndex  ?
                  colorBlue :
                  Colors.grey[100]))
            ),
            onTap: (){
             setState(() {

               int index_id = index; //if you want to assign the index somewhere to check


               toTimeListSelect[index] = !toTimeListSelect[index];
               toTimeListSelect[index] == true ? selectedToTime =dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'] : selectedToTime= ' ';
           
                 // if multiple timeslot is selected
                 if (arrayTimeStored.length > 0  && toTimeListSelect[index] == true) {
                   debugPrint("multiple time slot selected");


                   var previousResult = arrayTimeIndexStored[arrayTimeIndexStored
                       .length - 1];
                   int currResult = index_id;

                   debugPrint("previousResult:$previousResult");

                   debugPrint("currResult:$currResult");

                   if (currResult - 1 == int.parse(previousResult)) {
                     if (toTimeListSelect[index] == true) {
                       arrayTimeStored.add(dataSchedule[index]['time_slot']);
                       arrayTimeIndexStored.add(index_id.toString());
                     } else {
                       arrayTimeStored.remove(dataSchedule[index]['time_slot']);
                       arrayTimeIndexStored.remove(index_id.toString());
                     }
                   } else {
                     setState(() {
                       toTimeListSelect[index] = false;
                     });


                     Flushbar(
                       flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.GROUNDED,
                       icon: Icon(
                         Icons.error,
                         size: 30.0,
                         color: Colors.white,
                       ),
                       mainButton: ButtonBar(
                         children: [
                           GestureDetector(
                             onTap: () {
                          
                               Navigator.pop(context);
                             },
                             child: Text(
                               "Ok",
                               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                   fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                             ),
                           )
                         ],
                       ),
                       flushbarPosition:
                       FlushbarPosition.TOP,
                       reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.elasticIn,
                       forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.elasticOut,

                       messageText: Center(child: Text(
                         "You can only book slot in a row!", style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                       ),),),
                       //duration: null,
                       duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                     ).show(context);
                   }
                 } else { // else not multiple time slot selected

                   if(toTimeListSelect[index] == true) {
                     arrayTimeStored.add(dataSchedule[index]['time_slot']);
                     arrayTimeIndexStored.add(index_id.toString());

                   }else{
                     arrayTimeStored.remove(arrayTimeStored.last);
                     arrayTimeIndexStored.remove(arrayTimeIndexStored.last);

                   }
                 }

print(arrayTimeStored);

             });
            },
          );

        },),
    );
  }
```

I create couple of arrays to sort index of array, value of array and bool of array to add and remove when value of array is selected and deselected